# Any game server framework or engine that supports C# besides Scut and Photon?

Tags: c#, server, frameworks

I want to learn to use a game server framework or game server engine that supports C# and Http protocol. It doesn't have to be open-source or free, and it's OK if it only works well as small sized game server.
I heard about Scut and Photon, is there any other choice? It would be nice if it is a framework or engine with an active community so I can find some tutorials and guidance about it.

Comment: This question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.`

Comment: I'm sorry to create this thread here, may I ask where can I post this question?